# jquery graceful degradation ie5.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, graceful-degradation

What would be the best way of disabling jquery on an unsupported browser eg IE5.5. I just want to turn the errors off; I'm not trying to get it to work 100% properly or anything just to stop throwing errors; that's if it's not that big of a deal. If it is very difficult to do then I'm not that bothered.

Comment: You've found someone who still uses IE5.5?

Comment: to be honest if i asked that question about mosaic i still think it would be a legitimate question, but hey maybe history is not something stack exchange is bothered about

Comment: Well, for your sake, I don't think it's worth bothering with anything less than IE7, and IE6 if it's going to be a very widely used site. Alex (Alex's?) answer looks good though.

Comment: yes i'm well aware of that thanks; and as you probably already know google also just dropped support for ie8

Comment: Wondering if somebody still uses IE5.5 is also a good question!  IE6 usage is very low, but IE5.5 is a statistical zero.

Comment: News to me - thanks. It's probably pretty good if Google does that; it'll prompt people to use better (or newer - IE9) browsers to make web development that little bit easier.

Comment: @Sparky672 Agreed, hence my original comment. IE6 is still heavily used in China, for example, but I've had IE5.5 rear it's ugly, broken head _anywhere_ as far as I know.

Comment: yes true ie6 is bad but ie5 is a real disaster in comparison which is saying something

Comment: personally i applaud google but they actually already have the support built in - i opened gmail in ie6 and it's fine. Yet if we build a site or app from scratch not supporting ie6/7/8 it will tank and that's not good ... so i still develop for ie6 and will do for a year or two i think ( awful i know but ...)

Comment: What about IE2, IE3 or IE4; why not talk about them?  The whole point of the very first comment as well as mine is that the event horizon is now closing off on IE6.  It's bad enough we have to still deal with a couple older versions, let's not worry about the entire historical catalog of all browsers ever released.

Comment: i did mention them - i was saying "unsupported browser eg 5.5" - but i certainly wouldnt worry about them - i made that clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [HTML5 Boilerplate method](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html) to add a class to your `html` tag if the IE version is less than 6:

```
<!--[if lt IE 6]> <html class="ie5" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then put an `if` right at the top of your JS:

```
if ($('html.ie5').length !== 1) {
  // do stuff
}
```

**Edit**

Should have thought of this! Rather than doing that, just use the H5BP method when including your JS files:

```
<!--[if gte IE 6]><!-->
  <script src="jquery.js" text="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="application.js" text="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

This delivers the JS files to IE6+ and all other browsers.